# linebackgroundcolor overwriting backgroundcolor in \lstinputlisting

Tags: listings, backgrounds, lstdefinestyle

I am trying to highlight a specific line in a `\lstinputlisting` environment that already has a background color.  The approach that I tried removes my original background color and just highlights the specific line.

[image]

How to go about keeping the original background color **and** just highlight the specific line?

Here is what I have thus far:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.m}
 % detect if next step is an obstacle
                if bug.isoccupied(robot + [dx; dy])
                    bug.message('(%d,%d) obstacle!', n);
                    bug.H(bug.j,:) = robot; % define hit point
                    bug.step = 2;
                    % get a list of all the points around the obstacle
                    bug.edge = edgelist(bug.occgridnav == 0, robot);
                    %bug.k = 2;  % skip the first edge point, we are already there
                    bug.k = size(bug.edge,2)
                else
                    n = robot + [dx; dy];
                end
            end % step 1
\end{filecontents*}


\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
numbersep=8pt,
%language=Matlab,
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\mlttfamily\scriptsize,
%numbersep=22pt,
backgroundcolor=\color{blue!10}
}


\begin{document}


\lstinputlisting[firstnumber = 236,
style=mystyle,
linebackgroundcolor={\ifnum\value{lstnumber}=244\color{green}\fi},
caption={[First Change to the Bug2 Algorithm]{First Change to the Bug2 Algorithm}},
label = mat:line246]{\jobname.m}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to work if you add the background  color also to the line color. An alternative is to patch the internal command to add the background color:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.m}
 % detect if next step is an obstacle
                if bug.isoccupied(robot + [dx; dy])
                    bug.message('(%d,%d) obstacle!', n);
                    bug.H(bug.j,:) = robot; % define hit point
                    bug.step = 2;
                    % get a list of all the points around the obstacle
                    bug.edge = edgelist(bug.occgridnav == 0, robot);
                    %bug.k = 2;  % skip the first edge point, we are already there
                    bug.k = size(bug.edge,2)
                else
                    n = robot + [dx; dy];
                end
            end % step 1
\end{filecontents*}


\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
numbersep=8pt,
%language=Matlab,
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\mlttfamily\scriptsize,
%numbersep=22pt,
backgroundcolor=\color{blue!10}
}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
%alternative: patch \lst@bkgcolor 
%\xpatchcmd\lst@linebgrd{\color{-.}}{\lst@bkgcolor}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\lstinputlisting[firstnumber = 236,
style=mystyle,
%add background color to all lines:
linebackgroundcolor={\color{blue!10}\ifnum\value{lstnumber}=244\color{green}\fi},
caption={[First Change to the Bug2 Algorithm]{First Change to the Bug2 Algorithm}},
label = mat:line246]{\jobname.m}

\end{document}
```

[image]